# Query To Select then Extend Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, procedure

Sorry for the confusing title, but I wasn't sure how to define this issue.

The background is:
two tables - a customer table and an account table.
The tables are joined on a Customer ID number.
The Account Table contains a NAICS or SIC code field. 
This NAICS (SIC) code is used to select the customers. Only specific SICS are deined in the report specification. 
The customer, however, may have additional accounts under OTHER SIC or NAICS codes. 
Both the Accounts with the SIC or NAICS code that is used in the WHERE to filter for the customer AND any additional accounts linked to that customer must be selected.

A simplified version of the query is here:

```
SELECT
    dbo.CUSTOMER.customer_id, 
    dbo.CUSTOMER.customer_full_name,
    dbo.ACCOUNT.account_id,
    dbo.ACCOUNT.date_first_account_opened,
    dbo.ACCOUNT.NAICS_No,
    dbo.ACCOUNT.NAICS_description
FROM          
    dbo.CUSTOMER 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ACCOUNT WITH (nolock) 
        ON dbo.CUSTOMER.account_id = dbo.ACCOUNT.account_id     
WHERE
   dbo.account.NAICS)No in  ('6011','6062', '6021', '6022', '6035', '6036', '6029', '6081', '522110')-- SIC and NAICS codes
```

This code will return X number of customers and their associated accounts as selected by the condition in the WHERE clause. What I need to get are any OTHER accounts associated with a customer that are NOT in the WHERE filter list.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `WHERE dbo.account.NAICS NOT IN ('6011', ...`, because you can use `NOT` with `IN` in SQL.

Comment: The '6011' in the Account field is used to select the customer, so I can't use a NOT IN construction because it will pull all other Customers in. That's the problem.... the account is used to select the customer, then the customer has to be used to select all its associated accounts...

Answer (score 0):

When outer joining don't put criteria on it in the where clause. Your where clause turns your join into an inner join because only found matches have a NAICS_No. Move your where clause to the ON clause.

```
SELECT
    dbo.CUSTOMER.customer_id, 
    dbo.CUSTOMER.customer_full_name,
    dbo.ACCOUNT.account_id,
    dbo.ACCOUNT.date_first_account_opened,
    dbo.ACCOUNT.NAICS_No,
    dbo.ACCOUNT.NAICS_description
FROM          
    dbo.CUSTOMER 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ACCOUNT WITH (nolock) 
        ON dbo.CUSTOMER.account_id = dbo.ACCOUNT.account_id     
        AND dbo.account.NAICS_No in  ('6011','6062', '6021', '6022', '6035', '6036', '6029', '6081', '522110')-- SIC and NAICS codes
```

Comment: Haven't had a chance to incorporate this one yet - but I will Mon AM. Thanks for the direction in code and comment....

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    cu.customer_id, 
    cu.customer_full_name,
    ac.account_id,
    ac.date_first_account_opened,
    ac.NAICS_No,
    ac.NAICS_description
FROM          
    dbo.CUSTOMER cu
    INNER JOIN dbo.ACCOUNT ac
        ON cu.account_id = ac.account_id     
WHERE cu.customer_id in (--  List of customers with at least one "target" account
                         select distinct cu2.customer_id 
                          from dbo.CUSTOMER cu2
                           inner join dbo.ACCOUNT ac2
                            on ac2.account_id = cu2.account_id
                          where ac.NAICS_No in  ('6011','6062', '6021', '6022', '6035', '6036', '6029', '6081', '522110'))
```

The subequery gets a list of all customers with at least one of the specified accounts, and the "outer" query gets all accounts for those customers.

Comment: Adapted this for use... not sure what the results will be until I have  a chance to do a run... Thanks! It looks like it might do what I need it to do!